# Is it possible to use realm on back-end?

Tags: realm

Realm java is very dependent on Context which is not available on back-end. So is there a way to use it on backend ? For instance google app-engine or AWS

Answer (score 0):

Actually Realm only uses Context for `Context.getFilesDir()`. We are much more dependant on the Looper/Handler for communication between threads. So right now the Realm Library is tightly coupled to Android, but we do have plans to make it work on a normal JVM as well. Posting your use case here, will help us prioritize it accordingly: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2339

Comment: I'm thinking about synchronization my client with back-end by sending realm file instead for json in order to save traffic and time spent on serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 0):

Realm just released a Backend as a Service product that would fit in your needs [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/)